# Optimising changing column types

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, query-optimization

I've got an ETL script which changes the column types of a table to desired type and updates the data. The script works perfectly but I was wondering if there was a better & quicker way of doing it? Working in Redshift.

Current procedure;

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE p_alter_staging_tbls() AS $$
DECLARE
  row RECORD;   
BEGIN
  FOR row IN select * from 
  (
         select distinct table_name, column_name,data_type from staging.staging_col_info_v a order by a.table_name asc
    )
        loop    
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE staging.' || row.table_name || ' ' || 'ADD COLUMN ' || concat('new_',row.column_name) || ' ' || row.data_type ;
        EXECUTE 'UPDATE staging.' || row.table_name || ' ' || 'SET ' || concat('new_',row.column_name) || ' ' || '=' || ' ' || row.column_name || '::' || row.data_type  ;
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE staging.' || row.table_name || ' ' ||  'DROP COLUMN ' || row.column_name ;
        execute 'ALTER TABLE staging.' || row.table_name || ' ' || 'RENAME COLUMN '||  concat('new_',row.column_name) || ' ' || 'TO ' || row.column_name;
        END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

For optimization, you can check if the data type needs to be changed or if you already have the correct type and size.

For this purpose you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type,
  column_default, character_maximum_length, numeric_precision
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'staging' 
  AND table_name = row.table_name 
  AND column_name = row.column_name
```

and then check if "data_type" AND "numeric_precision" is different, in this case you can alter the column.

You can also consider to not create a new column, but you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name [SET DATA] TYPE new_data_type;
```

instead of:

```
EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE staging.' || row.table_name || ' ' || 'ADD COLUMN ' || concat('new_',row.column_name) || ' ' || row.data_type ;
EXECUTE 'UPDATE staging.' || row.table_name || ' ' || 'SET ' || concat('new_',row.column_name) || ' ' || '=' || ' ' || row.column_name || '::' || row.data_type  ;
EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE staging.' || row.table_name || ' ' ||  'DROP COLUMN ' || row.column_name ;
execute 'ALTER TABLE staging.' || row.table_name || ' ' || 'RENAME COLUMN '||  concat('new_',row.column_name) || ' ' || 'TO ' || row.column_name;
```

you can use this:

```
EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE staging.' || row.table_name || ' ' || 'ALTER COLUMN '||  row.column_name || ' ' || 'TYPE ' || || row.data_type;
```